# Где искать UTM метки? Нет ни в GET запросе ни в Cookies

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Подскажите где искать UTM метки у страницы? Мне говорят что достаточно зайти на сайт с Гугла или Яндекса, и тогда UTML метки якобы должны наличествовать. Но вот я смотрю:
- GET запрос
- Cookies запроса (страницы на сайте)
- Headers запроса

Нигде ничего похожего на utm*.. Максимум близкое по теме:

```
__unam (вида 7XXXXX3-15XXXXXXX7c-6dXXXXbd-XX
_ga GA1.2.88XXXXX45.14XXXXXX33
```

"Глобальная" задача: передавать UTM метки на сервер вместе с прочими данными формы. Но пока споткнулся об их получение…

Comment: ни гугл, ни яндекс не занимается проставлением меток в запрос

Answer (score 0):

Остановился на этой библиотеке:
http://sbjs.rocks/sourcebuster/data

Умеет не только UTM парсить.